# Work around for querying type of derived class

Tags: c++, object-oriented, polymorphism

I have an application where messages are collected and dispatched to various handlers. Messages are derived from the base class `MessageBase`, handlers derived from `HandleBase`, so what typically happens is a handler will receive a  `MessageBase` pointer. Now, the handlers need to know the derived type of message to determine how to process the message. I'm trying to avoid switch statements based off message types, so here is my work around...

`HandleBase` will have default virtual methods to handle all message types. Instead of passing the message to the handler, we pass the handler to the message, and the message hooks itself in to the right handler method.

Questions:

- Is there a name for this (pattern)?
- What are your thoughts? Is this what you would consider a good solution?

Here is the example code, feel free to review as well:

Header.h

```cpp
    #include <iostream>

    //Use smart enum to define message types
    #define MESSAGE_TYPES \
      ITEM(Start) \
      ITEM(Stop) \
      MORE_MESSAGE_TYPES

    #ifndef MORE_MESSAGE_TYPES
    #define MORE_MESSAGE_TYPES
    #endif

    //Create enum of all message types
    #define ITEM(x) MessageType_##x,
    enum MessageTypes
    {
      MESSAGE_TYPES
      MessageType_COUNT
    };

    template<int X>
    class Message;

    //Forward declare all Message types
    #undef ITEM
    #define ITEM(x) template<> class Message<MessageType_##x>;
    MESSAGE_TYPES

    class HandlerBase
    {
    public:

      //Add default handler methods for all message types
    #undef ITEM
    #define ITEM(x) virtual void Handle(Message<MessageType_##x> *) {std::cout << "Message not handled!\n";}
      MESSAGE_TYPES
    };

    //Test handler class
    class StartHandler : public HandlerBase
    {
    public:

      void Handle(Message<MessageType_Start> *);
    };

    //-- Messages ----------------------------------------------------------
    class MessageBase
    {
    public:

      virtual void Submit(HandlerBase *) = 0;
    };

    #define ADD_SUBMIT_METHOD(x) void Submit(HandlerBase * a_pHandler)\
    {\
      a_pHandler->Handle(static_cast<Message<x>*>(this));\
    }

    template<>
    class Message<MessageType_Start> : public MessageBase
    {
    public:

      ADD_SUBMIT_METHOD(MessageType_Start)
      int GetTime() {return 12;}
    };

    template<>
    class Message<MessageType_Stop> : public MessageBase
    {
    public:

      ADD_SUBMIT_METHOD(MessageType_Stop)
      std::string GetString() {return "System stopped!";}
    };
```

cpp

```cpp
    #include "Header.h"

    void StartHandler::Handle(Message<MessageType_Start> * a_pMsg)
    {
      std::cout << "System started at time = " << a_pMsg->GetTime() << '\n';
    }

    int main() 
    {
      Message<MessageType_Start> msgStart;
      Message<MessageType_Stop> msgStop;

      MessageBase * pMsgStart = & msgStart;
      MessageBase * pMsgStop = & msgStop;
      StartHandler handler;

      pMsgStart->Submit(&handler);
      pMsgStop->Submit(&handler);

      char t(0);
      std::cin >> t;
    }
```

Output:

```
    Started!
    Not handled!
```

Comment: Why not make your handler a virtual member function function of the message?

Comment: After a bit of reading, this appears to be the visitor pattern.